# How to fix VisualBrush lost line?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In WPF ,we can use VisualBrush do some thing like ppt's left side.

But I see the VisualBrush may lost the line in Rectangle when I zoom the VisualBrush to a small size.Like the image:

[image]

You can see VisualBrush lost the Bottom line.

But what I want is like the below image:[image]

When I try use the BitmapImage that use RenderTargetBitmap to get a image and use  linear interpolation algorithm to zoom will get a clearness image.

Can I change VisualBrush's algorithm I think it may use neighborhood-pixels algorithm.

Are there any printscreen algorithm that have a good performance like VisualBrush.

When I change my search key to `ViewBox` ,I can find the same question as this one :[how to avoid a single pixel line disappear in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29552339/6116637)

Comment: I think the ViewBox may be fundamental problem.

Comment: See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552339/how-to-avoid-a-single-pixel-line-disappear-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class named `TransformedBitmap` which can scale your `RenderTargetBitmap` with default scaling algorithm.

Use the code below:

```
public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this Visual visual, Size size)
{
    var bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(visual);
    var width = (int) Math.Round(bounds.Width);
    var height = (int) Math.Round(bounds.Height);
    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bitmap.Render(visual);
    return new TransformedBitmap(bitmap, new ScaleTransform(size.Width / width, size.Height / height));
}
```

I've tried this method in my demo and got the result below. You may noticed that the small rectangle in the left-top corner lost nothing.

[image]

Comment: Thx @walterlv ,I can zoom my rectangle to a small size.![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfNbD.png). But it cant use to get the input for it's not a control.